# Why is there no support for fans int the Smart Home API?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

How come there is no fan in the device types?  It seems kind of odd considering there is support for vacuums, washers, and dishwashers.  One of the main things that smarthome users want to control is their ceiling fan(s).  I can tell google assistant that it is a light, and I can set the speed, however I can't say things like "Set fan to low".  I have to say "dim the fan" or "set fan to 50%"  Also, will we ever be able to bind lights to individual google home devices.  For example, if I'm in the living room it would be much nicer to say "Turn off lights", instead of "Turn off living room lights".  If I say "turn off lights", it turns off all the lights in my whole house, which is pretty annoying.  It would be nice if the google team could use the term "all lights" or be able to group items like on amazon's platform.  This is a VERY big reason why a lot of home automation people choose the amazon product over the google product.  However, I feel the Google Home is a far superior product except for those few annoying things.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's feedback/rant, not a question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the feedback on the Fan device type. To be sure, we're continually adding more devices based on priority. However, as you mention we don't have a Trait to control the speed. Before we can encourage developers to use a fan, we would need to go through the process of adding a new trait. This process takes some time, so we've been prioritizing. I do like your clever workaround.

With respect to binding lights to rooms, that's also good feedback. One of the benefits of the HomeGraph is giving the Google Assistant a good understanding of the different devices in one has in different rooms. You can already group devices into rooms for better control.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question was asked, there is now a [Fan](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/guides/fan) device type with a [FanSpeed](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/fanspeed) trait.